NestQuery In Elastic search
NestQuery In Elastic search and it's dosen't work
I got data like this :
{
    "took": 17,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 6,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "candidate",
                "_type": "application",
                "_id": "4013361",
                "_score": null,
                "_routing": "64657bb087209b2b37c8f2f2",
                "_parent": "64657bb087209b2b37c8f2f2",
                "_source": {
                    "evaluation_records": []
                },
                "sort": [
                    1699897664000
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "candidate",
                "_type": "application",
                "_id": "4005398",
                "_score": null,
                "_routing": "636b73f187209b293dcd37a3",
                "_parent": "636b73f187209b293dcd37a3",
                "_source": {
                    "evaluation_records": []
                },
                "sort": [
                    1675245647000
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "candidate",
                "_type": "application",
                "_id": "4003184",
                "_score": null,
                "_routing": "6376e71787209b293dcd3917",
                "_parent": "6376e71787209b293dcd3917",
                "_source": {
                    "evaluation_records": [
                        {
                            "score": 0.0,
                            "account_id": null,
                            "create_time": "2023-01-12T11:07:23",
                            "provider": 4,
                            "project_id": "133",
                            "phase_id": 1170,
                            "project_title": "一个视频题-老",
                            "project_id_not_analyzed": "133",
                            "hr_id": 82752,
                            "status": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "sort": [
                    1673521621000
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "candidate",
                "_type": "application",
                "_id": "3995775",
                "_score": null,
                "_routing": "6275e73687209b47703a41ca",
                "_parent": "6275e73687209b47703a41ca",
                "_source": {
                    "evaluation_records": []
                },
                "sort": [
                    1668000149000
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "candidate",
                "_type": "application",
                "_id": "3997529",
                "_score": null,
                "_routing": "63041b6d87209b7edf3d1228",
                "_parent": "63041b6d87209b7edf3d1228",
                "_source": {
                    "evaluation_records": [
                        {
                            "score": null,
                            "account_id": null,
                            "create_time": "2022-09-02T16:19:55",
                            "provider": 3,
                            "project_id": "54",
                            "phase_id": 1170,
                            "project_title": null,
                            "project_id_not_analyzed": "54",
                            "hr_id": 82752,
                            "status": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "sort": [
                    1662133365000
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "candidate",
                "_type": "application",
                "_id": "3996285",
                "_score": null,
                "_routing": "6255328e87209b47703a410c",
                "_parent": "6255328e87209b47703a410c",
                "_source": {
                    "evaluation_records": [
                        {
                            "score": 23.2,
                            "account_id": null,
                            "create_time": "2022-09-19T15:45:32",
                            "provider": 3,
                            "project_id": "54",
                            "phase_id": 1170,
                            "project_title": null,
                            "project_id_not_analyzed": "54",
                            "hr_id": 82752,
                            "status": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "sort": [
                    1655291124000
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "CandidateProfileIdAgg": {
            "value": 6
        }
    }
}

when i useing query like :
{
                                "bool": {
                                    "should": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "should": {
                                                "bool": {
                                                    "should": {
                                                        "nested": {
                                                            "path": "evaluation_records",
                                                            "query": {
                                                                "bool": {
                                                                    "must": {
                                                                        "bool": {
                                                                            "should": [
                                                                                {
                                                                                    "bool": {
                                                                                        "must_not": {
                                                                                            "exists": {
                                                                                                "field": "evaluation_records"
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                },
                                                                                {
                                                                                    "bool": {
                                                                                        "must": [
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                "exists": {
                                                                                                    "field": "evaluation_records"
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                "terms": {
                                                                                                    "evaluation_records": []
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        ]
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            ]
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

and it's dosen't work , If I want to filter out data where "evaluation records": [], what should I do?
ES Mapping like this:
....
"evaluation_records": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "account_id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "create_time": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                            },
                            "hr_id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "phase_id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "project_id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "project_id_not_analyzed": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            },
                            "project_title": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            },
                            "provider": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "remark": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            },
                            "score": {
                                "type": "double"
                            },
                            "status": {
                                "type": "long"
                            }
                        }
                    }
...

Requirement is filter out records that have not been scheduled for evaluation exams.
Tried a lot of search methods are not good,

Use must condition with exist query in the nested query.
GET evaluation_nested/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "evaluation_records",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "evaluation_records"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

To reproduce try the following. (Note: The following codes for Elasticsearch v7 and higher)
PUT evaluation_nested
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "evaluation_records": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT evaluation_nested/_doc/1
{
  "evaluation_records": [
    {
      "score": 0,
      "account_id": null,
      "create_time": "2023-01-12T11:07:23",
      "provider": 4,
      "project_id": "133",
      "phase_id": 1170,
      "project_title": "一个视频题-老",
      "project_id_not_analyzed": "133",
      "hr_id": 82752,
      "status": 1
    }
  ]
}

PUT evaluation_nested/_doc/2
{
  "test_field": "value",
  "evaluation_records": []
}


#you will see only the _doc: 1
GET evaluation_nested/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "evaluation_records",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "evaluation_records"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


EDIT:
If you see the _doc 2 in the response check the following.
Instead of putting the must_not inside your nested query, you should put the nested query inside of a must_not. - reference


sorry bro, i want to get the _doc 2

No worries bro, I updated my answer please check.
